# How to get values based on other tables using foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So, I have this database:

[image: ERD Diagram]

[image: Tables]

Underlined = primary key

Bold = foreign key

Is there a way using SQL to:

1) Find the title of all those recordings that are on an album track.

2) Delete the track of recordingId 1 on albumId 1

Or is it impossible with that database design? If so, please, any tip on how I could improve it? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to databases.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh im using oracle

Comment: why do you need CD and an ALBUM table? CD has no meaningful attributes

Comment: So that there are no many to many relationships. It's a requirement for this scenario.

Comment: we can't provide feedback on your ERD w/o seeing your requirements

Comment: Basically, song can be recorded many times, recording can be released onto many albums, albums can consist of more than one CD. When a recording is released onto an album it becomes an album track. I'm supposed to do it so that there are no many to many relationships and so that the database is capable of answering the queries from my original post

Comment: I suggest you physically create these tables and their foreign keys, then go to your iTunes or CD collection, input the data, and then see if you can build the basic SQL to do what you want. When you get stuck, share all of this and a specific question - then you'll get better help. SO isn't the best place for advice on a data model

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I could ask for help with data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you've thought about your data model pretty well, but are having trouble getting started with writing your SQL.

It's kind of hard to answer this without example data, but here's some vague examples - maybe they'll get you started in the right direction.

1) Find the title of all those recordings that are on an album track.

```
select r.recordingID, s.songTitle -- you want the title
from song s                       -- so start with the song table
inner join recording r            -- match song to a recording
  on r.songid = s.songid
inner join albumtrack at          -- you only want recordings with an album track
  on at.recordingid = r.recordingid;
```

2) Delete the track of recordingId 1 on albumId 1

```
delete from albumtrack
where recordingID = 1
  and cdID = (select cdID from cd where albumID = 1);
```